# regex to match string before colon till whitespace

Tags: python, regex

i have a sample string from a text file. i want to find all the words before colon till whitespace.
i have written code like this:

```
import re
text = 'From: mathew <mathew@mantis.co.uk>\nSubject: Alt.Atheism FAQ: Atheist Resources\n\nArchive- 
name: atheism/resources\nAlt-atheism-archive-name:'
email_data = re.findall("[^\s].*(?=:)", text)
print(email_data)
```

Output:

```
['From', 'Subject: Alt.Atheism FAQ', 'Archive-name', 'Alt-atheism-archive-name']
```

Desired Output:

```
['From', 'Subject', 'FAQ', 'Archive-name', 'Alt-atheism-archive-name']
```

Code is picking up data till newline charater because of (.*) used. i want to restrict it till whitespace so i put [^\s] but its not working. What could i do instead?

Comment: Did my answer below help? Please let know.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
email_data = re.findall(r"\S[^:\s]+(?=:)", text)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gw3vXH) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ZFdEU/1).

**Details**

- `\S` -  a non-whitespace char
- `[^:\s]+` - 1+ chars other than `:` and whitespace
- `(?=:)` - immediately to the right, there must be a `:` char (it is not consumed, not added to the match value).

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.IGNORECASE` flag with the regex pattern

```
\b[a-z-]+(?=:(?:\s|$))
```

https://regex101.com/r/0UHsbo/1

https://ideone.com/oz91bP